# What is a Latin version of Inshallah?

Tags: idiom, medieval-latin, conjugation

Anyone who served in the military in Iraq (and probably anyone who has done business in the Gulf) in the last 15 years is familiar with the term 'Inshallah.' I suppose it means 'God willing,' as in, "I will do this thing, Inshallah." Realistically, it is used to evade responsibility while giving the listener a hope that divine intervention will allow the task at hand to be completed ([source](http://www.duffelblog.com/2016/06/arab-man-invents-inshallah-watch/)).

In this context, I was noticing the similarity between this expression and a very different one, 'Deus Vult,' the battle cry of the crusaders after the 1095 Council at Clermont. That, I understand, translates to "God wills it!"

The difference between the two is basically one of verb conjugation. As far as internet dictionaries tell me, 'vult' is the third person singular present indicative. To make it more of a question or conditional, you would want it to be in the subjunctive, I think, 'velit.'

**Would 'Deus Velit' express the same kind of abdication of responsibility in favor of divine will that 'Inshallah' represents?** If not, what would be the correct expression? And for any correct expression, are there records of this phrase being used in the past, perhaps in the more faithful Middle Ages?

Comment: _"Anyone who served in the military in Iraq (and probably anyone who has done business in the Gulf)"_ Or maybe people who, y'know, live there. This is an extremely US-centric introduction to your question. Did you think that only Americans are on the internet? I recommend editing your question to remove this bias.

Comment: Please be aware that DuffelBlog is a satirical publication. That doesn't mean their characterization of "inshallah" is _false_ - as satire is about highlighting the truth through absurdity - but I wouldn't say it's academic.

Comment: @undine_centimeter You were able to determine that DuffelBlog is satirical, but not that my quoting them was satirical?

Comment: @dbmag9 From a certain perspective (an extremely US-centric one), what I say is absolutely true. If you want to be offended, that is fine, but what I find much more interesting, and what I was asking about, is that the same root words 'god' and 'willing' are conjugated in such a way that their meaning is almost completely opposite in two different cultures. Fascinating!

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. No one yet who's actually a contributor here said anything about your wording.

Comment: @kingledion Your quoting does not appear "satirical" (in the loose sense of the word it seems you are using), in part due to the way you provided a source link in citation format without acknowledging the nature of the source as satire, and in part due to the fact that your question is inherently focused on the characterization used in the source, again without acknowledging its nature as satire.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I believe the introduction is US-centric because the one to ask it is from the US. Introducing a question from one's own point of view is what makes it real. I see why some might be offended, but to me this is a genuine question about Latin based on someone's own experience without an intention to hurt. Pointing out the bias in a comment is fair, but let us now focus on the question: how should this phrase be translated into Latin and how does it compare to *Deus velit/vult*?

Comment: The most recent edit made the beginning sentence ungrammatical, so I reverted it while fixing the capitalization in the title. If you wish to word it still, might I suggest something broader, like, "The Arabic *inshallah* is become more well-known in the West..." Or something along those lines, though personally, as @JoonasIlmavirta mentions, it's your question from your perspective, there's nothing wrong with the wording.

Comment: For what it's worth, _in sha'a Allah_ is three words - literally "if God wills it".  Having said that, I feel that _Deo volente_ is exactly the correct answer.  As far as I know, Arabic doesn't have anything like the ablative absolute.

Comment: @kingledion What do you mean by the meaning being almost completely opposite in two different cultures?

Comment: The Spanish got there quicker with a word transliterated directly from the Arabic: "Ojalá".

Comment: @Ian Just as [the Portuguese have *oxalá*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMWq4l_UWvk) (link to lovely rendition by Madredeus), again from the same "inch Alá" Arabic origin as one commenter observes.

Comment: insh'allah is not an abdication of responsibility, but a humble acknowledgement of man's role in things. As Thomas a Kempis said, "homo proponit, sed Deus disponit".

Comment: @JavaLatte With all due respect, words can mean whatever the speaker means with them. I do not pretend to know all the ways 'inshallah' is used among speakers of different languages, but I can tell you with great certainty that Iraqi army officers have used the term to evade responsibility. Its not like there aren't phrases that Americans or anyone else commonly use to evade responsibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common Christian formula is **Deo iuvante**, literally "with God helping", more naturally rendered in English as "with God's help" or "if God helps". It signifies that the matter in question will only be completed successfully if God favors it and actively cooperates.

The phrase has a long history. Google Books returns about 65,000 hits total for [*deo juvante*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deo+iuvante%22#tbm=bks&q=%22deo+juvante%22), [*deo iuvante*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deo+iuvante%22), [*juvante deo*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22juvante+deo%22), and [*iuvante deo*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22iuvante+deo%22). (Both spellings are equivalent, and the word order doesn't matter, though it's more common to put *deo* first.) In chronological order, here are some that seemed interesting.

---

[*The Last Pagans of Rome*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NHgvpINWV_QC&pg=PA381&dq=%22deo+iuvante%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidzJbY26rTAhVB74MKHWs1CVI4FBDoAQhIMAc#v=onepage&q=%22deo%20iuvante%22&f=false) takes use of **deo iuvante** in letters around 400 A.D. as evidence that their authors had converted from paganism to Christianity.

The [national motto of Monaco](https://books.google.com/books?id=jfrWCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA472&ots=j_o_kzpqsG&dq=%22deo%20juvante%22%20monaco%20motto&pg=PA472#v=onepage&q=%22deo%20juvante%22&f=false) is **Deo juvante**. The phrase appears on the coat of arms of its ruling family, the Grimaldis. Apparently this dates to 1297, when François Grimaldi took control of the city by a ruse involving soldiers dressed as monks.

[This odd book on freemasonry](https://books.google.com/books?id=OFEzAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22deo%20juvante%22&pg=PA288#v=onepage&q=%22deo%20juvante%22&f=false) reports records of acceptance in Latin of a high masonic degree ("Supreme Master") in a long series starting in 1324 and ending in 1804, nearly all with **deo juvante**, e.g.:

> Ego Arnaldus de Braque supremum magisterium **deo juvante** acceptum habeo anno domini 1340.

Around 1427, Thomas à Kempis wrote in *The Imitation of Christ,* [book 1, ch. 13](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/kempis/kempis1.shtml), "On resisting temptations":

> Qui tantummodo exterius declinat, nec radicem evellit, parum proficiet, imo citius ad eum tentationes redient, et pejus sævient. Paulatim, et per patientiam cum longanimitate **Deo juvante** melius superabis, quam cum duritia et importunitate propria.
>
> One who merely avoids [temptations] outwardly, not tearing out the root, will make little progress. Indeed, the temptations will return to him more quickly and rage worse than before. Little by little, through patience and long-suffering you will overcome them **with God's help** better than with harshness and your own crude ways.

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=i4ysAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22deo+juvante%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc5ILd76rTAhUm7YMKHS3UC-A4ChDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%22deo%20juvante%22&f=false) reports seven Dutch cargo ships, built from 1925 to 2008, named **Deo Juvante**, as well as other ships with the comparable names **Deo Favente** ("God favoring"), **Deo Volente** ("God Willing"), **Deo Confidentes** ("Trusting in God"), **Deo Gratias** ("Thanks be to God"), **Deo Data** ("Given by [or to] God"), and **Deo Duce** ("With God as the leader").

Usage continues to the present day. A [search on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=deo%20iuvante&src=typd) reveals one or two occurrences a month, sometimes stuck into sentences in other languages.

Comment: All this is true, but "in sha'a Allah" actually means "if God wills" or "God willing".  It doesn't mean "God helping" or anything to do with God's help.  So this is a correct answer to a different question, not this one.

Answer (score 25):

*Si Deus velit* would be quite satisfactory, 'if God should wish [it]', but is, I think, neither as usual or as forceful as the more familiar ablative absolute  form *Deo volente*, 'with God willing', often abbreviated as 'DV'.

On old British coinage, etc., *Dei Gratia*, by the grace of God' used to appear, later shortened to 'DG', with very similar meaning. [The full inscription included abbreviations for the phrases *Dei gratia Rex*, *Fidei Defensor* and *Indiae Imperator*, the last of which was dropped after independence was granted to India.]

Comment: Not quite sure how the second paragraph is related to the first, but FWIW current coins have the abbreviations DEI.GRA.REG.FID.DEF, since Elizabeth still is Queen by the grace of God, and Defender of the Faith.

Comment: I've never seen *Dei Gratia* used with promises or statements in the future tense, though. AFAIK the idea behind this phrase was that the monarch reigned as a sort of a feudal vassal of God, and the rite of coronation (which was considered almost an eighth sacrament) corresponded to the granting of Divine Grace to the new monarch.

Comment: I feel that these senses of _Dei Gratia_ might be better rendered in Arabic as _bismillah_, or _bi ismi Allahi_ (Arabic has lots of rules around silent vowels), which literally means "in God's name", but is commonly used the way _Dei Gratia_ is used here.

Comment: @DavidWallace: a closer approximation to Dei Gratia would be حمد  الله hamdulillah, which means "thanks to God".

Answer (score 20):

From [Bibliander's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Bibliander) translation of the [Qur'an, surah 18, ayah 69](http://quran.com/18/69),

> Dixit Moyses, **Deo uolente**, me quilibet sustinentem, nec te in quoquam offendentem semper inuenies.

This is not a literal translation.  The original Arabic, transliterated here into a more familiar alphabet is

> Qala satajidunee **in sha'a Allahu** ṣabiran wa la a`ṣee laka amra

Bibliander clearly felt that *Deo uolente* was the nearest Latin equivalent to the Arabic *in sha'a Allahu*.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for the answer!

Comment: Curiosity mostly, but what is the meaning of the `ṣ` character?

Comment: @KRyan—The ṣ grapheme is used to transliterate the Arabic letter ص, which represents the phoneme /sˤ/. English has no equivalent.

Comment: @SimpliciterChristianus thanks for that.  I was going to write a long paragraph about the differences between ص and س and now I don't have to.  Incidentally, I am firmly of the opinion that the sound of ص in Qur'anic Arabic is better represented by /sˠ/ than by /sˤ/, but that's just me.

Answer (score 20):

For a monotheist, Tom Cotton's answer is best; for a polytheist (like the ancient Romans), it would be in the plural, so something like [*dis volentibus*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=volentibus) ("with the gods willing").

Another way to word it, which is very similar to Tom Cotton's answer, is *si di volunt* ("if the gods wish it") or *si di volent* ("should the gods wish it").

Plautus *Bacchides* 239:

> Extexam ego illum pulchre iam, **si di volunt**.
> "Now I will beautifully unravel him, **if the gods are willing**."

Plautus *Poenulus* 911

> Hercle qui meus conlibertus faxo eris, **si di volent**.

Cicero *In Verrem* 2.3.157.10

> Fac sciat improbitatem aratorum; ipsi sudabunt, **si di
> volunt**.

*Historiae Augustae* 45.2.5

> scriptum esset: 'illa die, illa hora ab urbe sum exiturus et, **si di voluerint**, in prima mansione mansurus'...

Fronto *Ad M. Caesarem et Invicem* 5.58.1.4

> Sed venies saepe et tecum celebrabimus, **si dei volent**, omnia festa nostra.

Answer (score 11):

C.M. Weimer has given an expectedly excellent answer to the Latin part of this question. Otherwise, it might be permitted to add that the Muslim usage is in response to an explicit Qur’anic injunction (18:23) that one must not make any statement about the future without adding the proviso “if God wills”. This is not about “evading responsibility”. It is about the future not being predictable. Ever.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Do you perchance know the verse number?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer. 18:23

Comment: ...echoing very closely James 4:13-16. (ἐὰν ὁ Κύριος θελήσῃ; Si Dominus voluerit).

Comment: @fdb Those comments would make an excellent addition to the answer, since James 4:13-6 provides a phrase with the same religious meaning.

Comment: One English translation of these verses of the Epistle of James, chapter 4, is: _(13) Now listen, you who say, “Today or tomorrow we will go to this or that city, spend a year there, carry on business and make money.” (14) Why, you do not even know what will happen tomorrow. What is your life? You are a mist that appears for a little while and then vanishes. (15) Instead, you ought to say, “If it is the Lord’s will, we will live and do this or that.” (16) As it is, you boast in your arrogant schemes. All such boasting is evil._ (New International Version)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just checked two Arabic translations of James 4:15.  Both contain the phrase "in sha'a ar-Rabbu" (if the Lord wills), which of course has the same verb as "in sha'a Allahu".