# God is Vengeful Translation Help

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation, motto

I'm looking at getting a Latin phrase/quote on my arm and I'd like to know if the translation I'm thinking about using is correct. I've pulled some translations from this website ([Protected By God - Latin Discussion](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/protected-by-god.1537/)) and they seem to be correct but I would like the help of more knowledgeable people to confirm that.

These are the 'phrases' I'm looking to use:

- Deo Servante (With God protecting)
- Deo Custode (With God as a guardian)
- Deo Aegide (With God as a shield)
- Deo Patrocinante (With God protecting)
- Deo Patrono (With God as a guardian)
- Deo Praesite (With God protecting)
- Deo Tutamine (With God as a protecting force (trying to illustrate that it is neuter))
- Deo Tutante (With God protecting)
- Deo Vindicante (With God protecting/seeking vengeance)

I just want to know if these are the actual translations, but also if you can give me the translation for 'God is vengeful' or 'God will vindicate' than that is the actual translation I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To clarify your question, is there any specific meaning you like best for which you'd like the translation, or are you merely confirming the translations you found?

Comment: "Deo vindice" with God as avenger/protector was the motto of the Confederate States of America.  The verb "vindico" carries both meanings: protect and punish or avenge.  There are several bible verses that refer to God's vengeance, e.g. Romans 12: 19-21.  See https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Bible-Verses-About-Vengeance/

Comment: @Palizsche Hey, you might be able to shed some light on [this question about _vindice_](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4426/118) (including whether my answer, pieced together from various sources, was on track). The OP might want to have a look at that question, too.

Comment: [This answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4122/118) doesn't give you the word you're looking for, but the examples might shed some light on the meaning of the ablative case—especially the names of the Dutch ships. (All of your phrases above are in the ablative case.) Latin's ablative case is usually perfect for this sort of thing: terse, epigrammatic, and echoing lots of prior poetic usage and mottos.

Comment: @BenKovitz, thanks for asking -- I'll have a look, when I get a chance.  I still keep meaning to get back to your Gentleman and the Horace ode about "aurea mediocritas" too.  Latinitas longa, vita brevis.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question, I will confirm the translations provided, and the format will be Original Latin-English Translation.

> *Deo Servante* - With God protecting/preserving/guarding
>
> *Deo Custode* - With God the guard/protector/watchman
>
> *Deo Aegide* - With God the shield/defense
>
> *Deo Patrocinante* - With God defending/protecting
>
> *Deo Patrono* - With God the patron/advocate (I don't really like this one because *patronus* had a more specific cultural meaning, but it still works I guess.)
>
> *Deo Praesite* - *Praesite* most likely is a misspelling of *Praeside*, which would make the translation: With God the protector/guardian/defender
>
> *Deo Tutamine* - With God the means of protection/protection
>
> *Deo Tutante* - With God guarding/protecting/defending
>
> *Deo Vindicante* - With God claiming/vindicating/avenging

So now that you know what those phrases mean more closely, here are my suggestions for what you would like:

> God is vengeful - *Deus ultrix (est)*

In this one, *est* is the "is," and is commonly omitted in things like this, so feel free to include it or exclude it if you want.

> God will vindicate - *Deus vindicabit/iustificabit*

Both verbs mean vindicate, so choose only one, but I prefer *vindicabit* more because it has the more vengeful context you seem to be looking for.

Now, those are literal translations of the phrases about which you asked, but I have some other suggestions that may also work.

> *Deus Ultor/Vindicator* - God the Avenger

There was an actual Roman god named *Mars Ultor* or Mars the Avenger, so this makes sense as a construction, plus it sounds pretty cool in my opinion.

> *Deus Vindicaturus* - God about to Avenge

I don't prefer this one, but I though of it and it still has a similar meaning, so I figured I'd still put it here.

I hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: @Sam K Yes I am just looking for clarification. But If you could put me in touch with the literal quote of 'God is vengeful' that would be great! Many thanks.

Comment: Good answer. Two comments: 1. *Ultrix* is feminine, *ultor* is masculine. 2. I suspect it's supposed to be *praeside* from *praeses*, with D instead of T.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ultrix is a 1 termination adjective according to William Whitaker's Words, so I don't know if that changes anything. And I suspect you're right about _praeside_, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BlakeWebb I converted the answer into an actual comment. The question was asked from an unregistered account. Do you want to merge the two accounts? That would allow you to comment freely on answers to your own question.

Comment: Is [*ultrix*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dultrix) ever used to describe a masculine noun (or a singular neuter one)? The more common idiom indeed is [*deus ultor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ultor&la=la&can=ultor0#lexicon), "God the avenger." For the double nouns above, I'd also suggest using "as"; e.g. *Deo Aegis*, "With God as [My] Shield."

Comment: @cmw That is an interesting question about _ultrix_, as it doesn't appear that there are any examples. Perhaps this is a more uncommon construction, even limited in its uses, but I have found nothing to suggest it cannot be used in such a way.

Comment: @SamK I think the issue is that though it's an adjective, it's a feminine construction. The feminine form of the *-tor* suffix is *-trix*. There's even an [answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/183/78) about it. I would avoid.

Comment: @cmw But do these endings still apply for adjectives? Wouldn't the respective dictionary entry read _ultor_, _ultrix_, _ultrum_(?), instead of just _ultrix_, gen. _ultricis_? I have never heard of a gender-specific adjective, so maybe I am just misinterpreting your point?

Comment: It's an anomaly, for sure. I think it was at some point reclassified as an adjective based on its modifying a neuter plural noun, but it's morphologically similar to other feminine nouns of its type, like *nurtrix*, *matrix*, and *meretrix*. Using it with *deus* sounds highly unusual to my (admittedly imperfect and certainly not natural) ears.

Comment: @cmw Very interesting... I agree it does look a bit odd, and the trouble is that we can only guess at this point...

Answer (score 3):

**"If you could put me in touch with the literal quote of 'God is vengeful' that would be great!"**

Perhaps Nahum 1:2, as it appears in the Vulgate, is close to what you are after? The full verse is:

> *Deus aemulator et ulciscens Dominus ulciscens Dominus et habens furorem ulciscens Dominus in hostes suos et irascens ipse inimicis
> suis*
>
> A jealous and avenging God is the LORD, the LORD is avenging and
> wrathful; the LORD takes vengeance on his adversaries, and rages
> against his enemies (NRSV)

From which you could take the participial clause *Dominus ulciscens*, the LORD is vengeful. 'LORD' is translating the tetragrammaton of the Hebrew Bible; you could substitute *Deus* if you specifically want 'God' in the clause - *Deus ulciscens*.