# Is "Deo donante" a good translation of "God's blessing"?

Tags: translation-check

I want to write the words "God's blessing" in Latin. I came up with the translation *Deo donante* after a Google search. I want to double check if *Deo donante* means "God's blessing" and to understand what it means. What is the meaning of *donante*?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you come across this phrase? The translation (of any absolute ablative like this one) depends greatly on context, so you will get more useful answers if you can give more background. There is no single universal translation.

Comment: I totally agree with the earlier comment. I can think of six. Here's one. ***"If God is the giver, ..."*** If that doesn't fit, be a bit more precise, and ask again. Or ***"When God gives, ..."***

Comment: I want to write the words 'God's blessing' but in the Latin language and want to double check if 'Deo donante' means God's blessing?

Comment: @Lynette Thanks for the comment! I edited your question accordingly. One thing still puzzles me: Where did you find *Deo donante* as a translation of "God's blessing"? Is it your own attempt or did you find it in a book or online? Please edit your question if you have anything to add, and also feel free to undo (rollback) my edit if you want to.

Comment: Thank you Joonas for your input so much appreciated.  I have done a google search by typing the question:  "What is God's blessing in the Latin language?  The direct translation 'Deo donante ' came-up.  I want to use this name on a business card but needs to ensure this is the meaning.

Comment: If Ben's answer satisfies your needs, can you tick the green check mark next to his answer to accept it? You have earned enough reputation with this question to be able to vote. You can go around the site and vote on any questions and answers you like.

Comment: Ego accipio benedictionem Dei
I am receiving God's blessings

Answer (score 7):

"God's blessing" in Latin is **benedictio Dei**.

This phrase appears in the last sentence of the Pope's [Blessing to the City and to the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbi_et_Orbi) (*Urbi et Orbi*):

> Et **benedictio Dei** omnipotentis, Patris, et Filii, et Spiritus Sancti, descendat super vos et maneat semper.
>
> And may the **blessing of** almighty **God**, the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit come down on you and remain with you always.

It's not a distinctively Catholic phrase, though. Latin is an international language, and the early Protestants used this same phrase. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=jvJKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22benedictio%20dei%22) is some discussion of John Calvin's belief that life is a *benedictio Dei.*

---

**Deo donante** literally means "with God giving". In English, the *-ing* form of a verb serves as both present participle, i.e. as an adjective, as in "The man now **surfing** is the defending champion", and as gerund, i.e. as a noun, as in "The **surfing** today is wonderful." In Latin, the present participle and gerund have distinct endings. *Donante* is a present participle, not a gerund, so it's probably not appropriate for what you have in mind, as it sounds like you want a noun to denote God's blessing, not a modifier for something else. It's also in the [ablative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)), which provides a wonderfully concise way to express some kinds of thoughts, but it might not suit what you have in mind. See my explanation of the related phrase *Deo iuvante* [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4122/118) for more detail.

Corresponding words in different languages often have a slight difference in meaning or connotation. So here's a little more information to give you a little of the "feel" of *benedictio* in Latin. *Benedictio* is a compound word: **bene** means "well", the root of English words like "benevolent" and "beneficial"; and **dictio** means "a saying, talk, oratory", whence English "dictionary". The English word "benediction" is of course a direct borrowing of Latin *benedictio.* Here's an example of its usage in [St. Jerome's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome) translation of Genesis 26:28–29:

> Qui responderunt "Vidimus tecum esse Dominum et idcirco nunc diximus sit iuramentum inter nos et ineamus foedus ut non facias nobis quicquam mali sicut et nos nihil tuorum adtigimus nec fecimus quod te laederet sed cum pace dimisimus auctum **benedictione** Domini."
>
> They responded, "We saw that thou art with the Lord and for that reason we then said, 'Let there be an oath between us, and let us enter into a covenant that thou do us no harm just as we have touched nothing of thine nor have we done anything that would harm thee; but with peace we sent thee away enriched **with the blessing** of the Lord.'"
>
> <sup>Translation mine, written to make the parallels between the Latin and English as easy to follow as possible.</sup>

*Benedictione* is the ablative of *benedictio,* indicating its connection with [*auctum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auctus#Latin) (enriched).

Answer (score 6):

*Deo donante* is not a good translation.
It is an absolute ablative and has numerous meanings.
Depending on context, it can mean "while/when/because/if God gives", and there is no single universal translation.

*Deo donante* plays a very different grammatical role than "God's blessing".
The English phrase is essentially a noun, whereas the Latin one is essentially a subordinate clause.
This is not technically precise, but I just wanted to point out the difference in nature.

The genitive "God's" is best translated as the Latin genitive *Dei*.
The main problem in translating "God's blessing" is finding a good word for "blessing".
You can look up any noun you like in [any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) and use it as such.
I agree with Ben Kovitz that the most appropriate word seems to be [*benedictio*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2006437).
Therefore ***benedictio Dei*** is my suggestion.

There are many horrible Latin translations out there, and [Google Translate excels at producing more](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79), so it is wise to consult someone who understands Latin in matters of any importance.
I would of course suggest this site. ☺